# Characters allowed in CookieDecoder

Tags: netty

My company uses a lot of legacy cookies that contain '=' and ',' in the cookie value. An example would be: A=v=1&lg=en-US,it-IT,it&intl=it&np=1;T=z=E . Right now it is not possible to get rid of those cookies and we need Netty to not throw an IllegalArgumentException on validating those cookies. Are there any suggestions? Would it be okay to submit a patch to CookieDecoder, maybe read in some env variable which will pick the right regex accordingly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netty 3.5.1.Final has no problem decoding the cookie you mentioned:

```
@Test
public void testDecodingValuesWithCommasAndEquals() {
    String src = "A=v=1&lg=en-US,it-IT,it&intl=it&np=1;T=z=E";
    Set<Cookie> cookies = new CookieDecoder().decode(src);
    Iterator<Cookie> i = cookies.iterator();
    Cookie c = i.next();
    assertEquals("A", c.getName());
    assertEquals("v=1&lg=en-US,it-IT,it&intl=it&np=1", c.getValue());
    c = i.next();
    assertEquals("T", c.getName());
    assertEquals("z=E", c.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for looking into this! We are using 3.3.1.Final and the CookieDecoder logic is totally different, that explains a few thing. Thanks again!